# Upload media error: unable to create directory (windows hosting)

Tags: uploads, windows

Trying to upload any kind of media on a new WP install is failing due to a messed up media folder path:

> Unable to create directory D:\webs\bucmio\wp/wp-content/uploads. Is
>   its parent directory writable by the server?

The reason why it's not working is obvious, but how can I correct it?  I'm guessing I need to get the full path in the `Settings > Media` but how to find it?

The host is Cbeyond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to ensure chmod permissions on wp-content are set to 0755.  (i know sometimes i have to go 0777 even though i am fairly sure that isn't advisable)  i usually do this w/ folder properties in my FTP client, but i'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: I don't think the problem has to do with permissions as much as the back slashes and forward slashes in the path, but I will look into the permissions too.

Comment: PHP in Windows actually doesn't care about the wrong slashes. The directory permissions are definitely your problem. However, "0777" has no meaning in Windows hosting, so you'll need to do some other approach to make that directory writable.